# Replacing H2 in the entire Spring Boot app

Tags: spring-boot, testcontainers

I have a Spring Boot app which appears to use H2 when building to run Liquibase commands on. It also appears that Unit Tests run against H2.

I'm digging into whatever makes this work behind the scenes.

Is there a way to bring `testcontainer:mysql` into my `application.yaml` without all the configuration code I'm seeing in examples elsewhere?

Something like this:

```yaml
spring:
  config.activate.on-profile: local
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/external_engagement_proxy?useSSL=false&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance&useCursorFetch=true&profileSQL=true
    username: root
    password: root
  jpa.show-sql: true
```

The intent is that the `testcontainer:mysql` Docker would be used when I build (to run Liquibase commands against) and that the Docker would also be used by default for all Unit Tests.

Comment: All the `configuration code` you don't "like" is used to launch testcontainers before running your tests